# Get 500 internal server error when calling an arcgis rest services in C#

Tags: c#, server, arcgis

I get an internal server error 500 while calling an arcgis rest services. However, i test it at local it work smooth, but when deploy on the server, it cannot work and get 500 error when the method is called. The below is the method that i write to call the arcgis rest services. Anyone can help me?

```
private string coordinatevalidation(string lon, string lat)
        {

            string location = lon + "," + lat;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            string strurl = string.Format("https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/reverseGeocode?f=pjson&featureTypes=&location=" + location);
            HttpWebRequest requestObjGet = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strurl);
            requestObjGet.Method = "Get";
            HttpWebResponse responseObjGet = null;

            responseObjGet = (HttpWebResponse)requestObjGet.GetResponse();

            string strresult = null;
            using (Stream stream = responseObjGet.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                strresult = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }

            return strresult;
        }
```

Comment: This is a debugging and analysis problem and likely one of a number of possible problems. As it stands this question is relatively unanswerable

Comment: Thanks for the replay. That mean the coding should be no problem is it?

Comment: Look in the server's Windows event logs - the Application log - to see a more complete error message. If there is a .pdb file for the .dll then it should be able to give more information.